# AutoFac / Unity Container - Dependency Injection with multiple implementations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac, unity-container

I am going to work with Dependency Injection for a ASP.NET Web API project.

I understand how constructor Dependency Injection works, but i can't resolve how to make the injector choose between two implementations of the same interface. Lets say for an example that we have an interface like this:

```
public interface ISender
{
    void Send();
    void AddReceipment(User user);
}
```

Then lets say i have 2 implementations of this `SmsSender` and `MailSender` using the same `ISender` interface.

Now i have two API controllers lets call them "MailController" and "SmsController".

Now i want the dependency injector to inject `ISender` into the MailController with the implementation of the class `MailSender` and in the SmsController i want to inject `ISender` too, but with the implementation of the class `SmsSender`.

Is that possible using AutoFac or Unity container?

If it is, then how would i aproach that?

Comment: According to the Autofac docs, you have 4 options to achieve this: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Autofac docs, you have 4 options to achieve this:

1. [Redesign your interfaces](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html#option-1-redesign-your-interfaces)
2. [Change the registrations](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html#option-2-change-the-registrations)
3. [Use keyed services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html#option-3-use-keyed-services)
4. [Use metadata](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html#option-4-use-metadata)